# SSH is not listening on port 443

Tags: ssh

I have locked all ports except `80` and `443`. When changing the port on a server VPS from `22` to `443`, I can not connect to a remote server.

When I connect to the network from a mobile phone, I can make a connect to SSH on port `443`.

I have bought the VPS server with a public IP address with the ability to remotely connect to it via SSH or through the panel. All ports are blocked by the firewall in the company

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Please add to the post location of the VPS, how the connection from the mobile is different, where you are connecting from in both cases, how and where you have locked the ports and if there are corporate firewall involved or at home.

Comment: I wouldn't change the ssh port to a reserved port. 443 is https by default.

Comment: I would say layer 7 firewalling, the confusing part is saying you can do SSH in your phone.

Comment: What OS? Do you run web server on the VPS? What errors you get?

Answer (score 4):

Since you can connect to ssh on your VPS on port 443 via mobile phone, the sshd is running just fine there.

What is probably happening, is that company is (in addition to blocking all other ports) doing layer7 filtering - eg. making sure there is only HTTPS traffic on port 443, not any other (like ssh).

Firstly, you really should talk to appropriate people in charge on that policy and exceptions. **Trying to break the rules can get you fired**. They may allow ssh to your VPS if that is needed for purposes of work, or offer other options.

Other than that, you can install some [webshell](http://www.binarytides.com/web-shells-tutorial/) on https (apache or such) on that VPS, and use that as remote shell. Not that I'd recommend it (not least because they are mostly used for exploits)...